# How can I "load" content without include/require?

Tags: javascript, php, class, include, require

Ey guys.

How can "load" a php file into another without require or include? For example, can I in load my footer, header etc. in my index.php from another file? With for example a php class, even javascript would be fine ? (much like auto_apend/prepend .htacces). But I do not want to use .htacces..

Thanks!